Azure Data Explorer calculate history of changes
I have a table, which shows, when a service was booked or removed for a device.
let devices=datatable(device:string, timestamp:datetime, bookedServices:dynamic) [
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-11), dynamic(["service1", "service2"]),
    "device-2", datetime(2024-06-11), dynamic(["service1", "service2"]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-13), dynamic(["service2"]),
    "device-3", datetime(2024-06-14), dynamic(["service3"]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-16), dynamic([]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-19), dynamic(["service1", "service2"])
];

So in that example, service1 and service2 was booked for device1 on June, 11.
On June, 13, service1 was removed.
On June, 16, service2 was also removed for this device.
On June, 19, both services was booked again.
With the data, I want to create an overview, which service have currently how many devices booked.
Important: So not only the dates, when a service was booked is from interest!



Service
Timestamp
NumberOfDevices




service1
2024-06-11
2


service2
2024-06-11
2


service1
2024-06-13
1


service3
2024-06-14
1


service2
2024-06-16
1


service1
2024-06-19
2


service2
2024-06-19
2



I could get the currently booked services with this query:
devices
| summarize arg_max(timestamp,*) by device
| mv-expand bookedServices to typeof(string)
| summarize count() by bookedServices

But I have no idea, how to get a history table like shown above.
Update:
Also a table, which shows the number of devices per service per day would be nice! (so not only a row if something changed)

Based on your input data, on date 2024-06-16 there are no services. But in your expected output, there is service2 and no.of devices are 1. Please check and let me know if the input data and expected output matches or not?

Would the expected output be something like this https://i.imgur.com/2j9ZNdN.png for the above sample input?

@RakeshGovindula the input should be correct, as on 2024-06-16, device2 has still service2.


Also a table, which shows the number of devices per service per day would be nice

As per your input data, you can achieve the number of devices on each day per each service using below query.
let devices=datatable(device:string, timestamp:datetime, bookedServices:dynamic) [
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-11), dynamic(["service1", "service2"]),
    "device-2", datetime(2024-06-11), dynamic(["service1", "service2"]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-13), dynamic(["service2"]),
    "device-3", datetime(2024-06-14), dynamic(["service3"]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-16), dynamic([]),
    "device-1", datetime(2024-06-19), dynamic(["service1", "service2"])
];

devices
| mv-expand bookedServices to typeof(string)
| summarize NumberOfdevices = count() by bookedServices,timestamp
| order by timestamp asc;

Output:


This answer is unfortunately not correct. As On 2024-06-16, service1 should be 1.
On 2024-06-19, service1 and service2 should be 2 again.

Maybe one hint:
The entries just show a change of the booked services per device. So device3 booked service3 in 2024-06-14 and afterwards there is no change. So number of devices for service3 will still be today 1 and not only on 2024-06-14.

Can you edit your question and explain your conditions to achieve your requirement? It's quite hard to make assumptions based on your hints.

Are you saying that, if any new entry for any device entered for example with services none [], then the services assigned for this device should not be counted. And it should be like this for every entry? If this is the case, I think, you should have a list of all services and all devices and then make a comparison table based on that for every entry. Please clarify if I am wrong.

I tried to update the description. Maybe it's more clear now!

Understood your question, let me try and update the answer.
